# Setup WP usin Docker container on UBUNTU server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose

I am using docker to install nginx, WP, MariaDB on my ubuntu server.
As per  https://dev.to/foresthoffman/hosting-wordpress-over-https-with-docker-5gc this tutorial I am creating folder and docker-composer.yml file.
My .yml file code

```
    version: '3.3'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx-wordpress
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-wordpress:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx-wordpress.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs/nginx-wordpress:/var/log/nginx
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginxproxy_default
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginxproxy_default
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - '9000'
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wpprefix_
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginxproxy_default
networks:
  nginxproxy_default:
    external: true
```

When I am compiling `docker-composer up` command it is installing `Nginx` and `WP` in docker's overlay folder. Little bit confusing here how I can Map `WP` container with `/var/www/html` and `Nginx` Container with `/etc/nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

Your local folder `./wordpress` is mapped to the container's `/var/www/html`

Ergo:

```
./wordpress:/var/www/html
```

Pretty similar mount mapping for nginx:

```
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-wordpress:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx-wordpress.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs/nginx-wordpress:/var/log/nginx
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
```

Please read the [Docker(-composer)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) documentation.

Also there are hundreds of such examples out on the web :)